# Listen to app wake up event / schedule a wake up event

Tags: android, events, sleep, wakeup

I'm trying to schedule event. For example, i'd like for something to happen 1 hour from now. For this i used handler postdelayed. Unfortunetly, this doesn't work as expected. I guess the reason is that android puts my app to some kind of sleep state, so the timer freezes at some point, and keeps counting from the point stopped when the device is back to use. This causes the event to occur at unknown time, greater than the time expected.

Now, i have two ways to solve this and i'd like to know how to implement each one:

1. Schedule to wake the device at a specific time and then excecute the event. I don't know how to schedule a wake up (and do it efficently).
2. Excecute the event as soon as my app wakes, if the time of execution has passed (i can use date and time to verify if the time passed). What i miss here is how to listen to wake up event.

And for my general knowledge about android sleep policy: Does android put services and activities to sleep automatically? how, if so, any messaging app keeps listening to new messages?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Alarms](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html),
Alarms  give you a way to perform time-based operations outside the lifetime of your application.

android has 4 types of Alarms :

1. [ELAPSED_REALTIME—Fires:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#ELAPSED_REALTIME) the pending intent based on the amount of time since the device was booted, but doesn't wake up the device. The elapsed time includes any time during which the device was asleep.
2. [ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP—Wakes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP): up the device and fires the pending intent after the specified length of time has elapsed since device boot.
3. [RTC](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC)—Fires: the pending intent at the specified time but does not wake up the device.
4. [RTC_WAKEUP—Wakes:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC_WAKEUP) up the device to fire the pending intent at the specified time.

Read this pages [Alarms](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)